# Where's the bottle neck? (Hotspot repeater network)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, hotspot, repeater

Hotspot - Router (connected wireless to hotspot using wisp/repeater mode with DHCP) - wired to various APs.

```
hotspot  ))) ((( Router ---wired---- AP ))) (((wireless devices
```

All devices are wireless N except the hotspot, which supports AC.

Wired clients get maximum speed. Wireless clients get much less.

I'm well aware of the speed loss issue with repeaters/airtime. But in this setup, there are two radios between client and the final hotspot which should help some.

Wireless phone - AP wired to Router - wireless hotspot

Is there a more optimum setup option with a wireless only hotspot? Hopefully I explained the setup clearly.

Comment: Are they at the very least on different (non-overlapping) channels?

Comment: There are many, many reasons why you may get degraded wifi performance in this setup. Physical distance, interference, channel and radio settings, client settings, router settings, etc. You haven't really posted any troubleshooting you have performed, or any results from any performance tests in different configurations. You should at least ensure each AP is using a different channel, and look at competing SSIDs in the area to plan around them.

Comment: Yeah seperate channels. No overlap. No other wifi networks in the area, just mine

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see. You use cellular hotspot connection instead of broadband/DSL modem.

Usually cellular hotspots are quite weak, you need to use a router as a repeater for extending the connection range. So the internet connection becomes quite slow.

If the number of devices is less, then you even can't use the router and directly connect devices to the phone, but connecting a lot of devices will be harmful to the phone.

Wired clients should get more speed than wireless clients, so if possible try to connect wireless clients more.

Sorry, but there are no better setup otherwise you use a high speed broadband or DSL connection.